# Passing a value in Command function in a column for Kendo UI Grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I want to add a button in a Kendo UI grid which will redirect to a different site the URL is created dynamically in a function based on the environment and a ID field for that respective row is passed in the URL. So I added a command column in the grid but I am not sure how to pass the ID to that function . Please help .
Below is not working for me

```
{ command: { text: "View", click: "getredirectURL(#=Id#)" }, title: " ", width: "100px" }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? How is the HTML code actually generated? Your command definition should be `{ command: { text: "View", click: getredirectURL(#=Id#) }, title: " ", width: "100px" }`. Don't add quotation marks to the `getredirectURL` function.

Comment: The HTML just have a div which in js is am initiating as grid.  'var grid = $("#getSGrid").kendoGrid({
                     dataSource: sDataSource,
                     resizable: true,
                     columns: [
                     { command: { text: "View", click: getredirectURL(#=series_Id#) }, title: " ", width: "100px" },
                     { field: "Name", title: " NAME", width: 100 },
                     { field: "Description", title: " DESCRIPTION", width: 50 },                   
                     ],
                 }).data("kendoGrid");'

Comment: If I am not adding the double quotes I am getting syntax error on #=Id#

Comment: The formating (parameter binding) does not work that way.

Comment: Can you please tell what is wrong? or what should be the correct way to pass parameter.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're creating your grid using just the JavaScript API. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are configuring the `click` event wrong. As per the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.command.click), you need to set the JavaScript function which gets executed when the command button is clicked. You cannot set the parameters of this function using templating (i.e. `#=Id#`). The function receives a jQuery Event as an argument (copy-paste statement).

You need to do the following:

```
click: function(e) {
      // e.target is the DOM element representing the button
      var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
      // get the data bound to the current table row
      var data = this.dataItem(tr);

      //the "data" variable is now the entire "object" and has properties
      //you now have access to the Id property so just call your function
      getredirectURL(data.Id);
}
```

You might want to add a `debugger;` and start inspecting the `e` event and the `this` object inside the function. There are many interesting things inside.